# PHP - How to unserialize data using ( UNSERIALIZE )

Tags: php, serialization

Here is a code which serialize data and then unserialize it.

```
 class magicmethod {
protected $name = array('Arfan','Azeem','Haider');
protected $fruit = array('Apple','Bannana');
protected $animal = 'Cat';

public function __sleep(){
    return array('name','animal');
}

public function __wakeup(){
    echo 'Going to Unserialized'; 
}
  }

$obj = new magicmethod;

$ser = serialize($obj);

var_dump($ser);

var_dump(unserialize($ser));
```

I just serialize `$name` and `$animal` saved it in variable name `$ser`. After this 
I unserialized this var `$ser` see that it unserialize all the class `magicmethod` it can also return the `fruit array` How it can do that I can not serilize all the class.
I want to get only those result which I serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this behavior because those are set up as defaults for the properties... if you look at this example it will behave the way you expect.

```
class magicmethod {
    protected $name;
    protected $fruit;
    protected $animal;

    public function setData(){
        $this->name = array('Arfan','Azeem','Haider');
        $this->fruit = array('Apple','Bannana');
        $this->animal = 'Cat';
    }
    public function __sleep(){
        return array('name','animal');
    }

    public function __wakeup(){
        echo 'Going to Unserialized'; 
    }
}

$obj = new magicmethod();
$obj->setData();
$ser = serialize($obj);
print_r($ser);

print_r(unserialize($ser));
```

What is happening is that when unserialize occurs it creates a new object from the class definition (but bypasses the constructor) and then overlays the serialized data onto the classes properties. If you look carefully at the serialized values data you will notice that the fruits definition is absent.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `unserialize()`, you create a new `magicmethod` object with the default `$fruit` value. The fruit-array is not part of your serialized data, but comes from your class definition.